# How does Elen's attitude layout the last scene of the final episode?

Tags: requiem-for-the-phantom

In the last scene of the show we see Reiji and Elen in Mongolia standing in the fields and Reiji ends up shot and--I'm assuming--killed by the man on the wagon passing by. However Elen's emotions don't reflect this at all.

From what I know, the show is setup to favor Elen and Reiji being together with their bond they slowly developed throughout. However, when Elen looks back at Reiji she is smiling happily thinking. "These memories are enough for me," and goes to lay down in the grass paying no mind to him.

My thoughts on what happened:

- First off, the ending scene goes from them being together mid-day to each of them in separate scenes at sunset.

  1. Elen is thinking back on her times with Reiji, after the point of his death. Which happens to be at the same place and time of day that he died. Elen says, "I have memories of being with you," which could possibly be referring to a flashback from before Reiji died.
  2. I'd like to point out that she could possibly have planned his death, although unlikely. Since that wouldn't fit with the dialogue of her thinking back about Reiji.